# IE8 problem when using fancybox to show embedded blip.tv videos

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox, embedded-video

I am using the latest fancybox 1.3.1 and jquery 1.6. I am trying to embed a video from Fancybox. I know Fancybox has built-in support for YouTube, but the video and Fancybox link were provided by a client, so I can't use another service. Fancybox doesn't appear to have built-in support for blip.tv.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
<div style="float: right; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <a id='video' href='#data'><img src='images/gift_btn.JPG' border='0' 
        alt='Learn How to Make An Online Gift'/></a>
    <div style='display:none'>
        <div id='data'>
            <embed src="https://blip.tv/play/hYwWgrniXAA" 
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="392" 
                allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#video").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

This works great on FireFox, but IE8 only shows a grey box.

---

Some additional information that I don't think matters, but in case it does:

- In production, the page is always served over https:// (they want the video embedded on the log in page), thus I'm using https:// on the blip.tv link above.
- I had another problem with Fancybox not displaying images in IE8, and I followed [these directions](http://www.crustiz.com/php-jquery/jquery-fancybox-plugin-images-not-working-on-ie-how-to-fix/) to fix it.

If I'm missing any important information, please let me know and I'll update the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing an `<object>` tag in your flash embed, which is why it might not be working in IE. See this Adobe KB article on the subject:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html